# Create executable JAR from ANTLR source files

Tags: jar, antlr, antlr4, packing

I have done some work and I just realized that I can execute it only with TestRig (grun).
Is there a way how to pack these files together? What files are needed to be in that JAR?
And is there a tutorial?

Thanks for feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you wrote, I suppose you have only written the grammar (.g4 file). What you need is of course to write a main function to invoke parser. Before that you need to generate code java code from the g4 file.

As for the tutorial, I guess the same place where you found the testrig would be a good start.